# Add a tooltip to a D3 horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, popup, tooltip

I'm trying to add a tooltip popup to show the year and the value when I hover the mouse over the bar. But for some reason, all the options I have tried do not work. Anyone have any solutions?

I have tried a variation of this link [here](https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_tooltip.html) but have had no luck. In many cases, the tooltip does not appear in the right location.

Could someone help to create a minimalistic solution?

HTML

```
            <div class="bar-chart-container">
                <svg class="bar-chart"></svg>
            </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// Bar chart
function startBarChartAnimation() {
    if (isInViewport(document.querySelector(".bar-chart-container"))) {
        const data = [
            { year: "2019", value: 11 },
            { year: "2020", value: 10 },
            { year: "2021", value: 23 },
            { year: "2022", value: 37.4 },
        ];

        const svg = d3.select(".bar-chart");
        const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 60 };
        const width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".bar-chart-container")).width) - margin.left - margin.right;
        const height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".bar-chart-container")).height) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        // Add the gradient definition
        const gradient = svg.append("defs")
            .append("linearGradient")
            .attr("id", "bar-gradient")
            .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("x2", width)
            .attr("y2", 0);

        gradient.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "0%")
            .attr("stop-color", "#80bede");

        gradient.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "100%")
            .attr("stop-color", "#acd6d9");

        const x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
            .range([0, width]);

        const y = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map(d => d.year))
            .range([0, height])
            .padding(0.3);

        const g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

        // Create and append the bars
        g.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("y", d => y(d.year))
            .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
            .attr("fill", "url(#bar-gradient)")
            .attr("width", 0)
            .transition()
            .duration((d, i) => 500 + i * 200)
            .attr("width", d => x(d.value))

        g.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
            .call(g => g.selectAll("line").remove()) // Remove y-axis lines
            .call(g => g.selectAll("path").remove()) // Remove y-axis lines
            .call(g => g.selectAll("text") // Change font color of y-axis labels
                .style("fill", "#bbbbbb") // Change the fill color here
            );


        // Remove the scroll event listener once the animation is triggered
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", startBarChartAnimation);
    }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", startBarChartAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your JavaScript code:

```
const tooltip = d3.select(".bar-chart-container")
    .append("div")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("id", "tooltip");
  const mouseover = function(event, d) {
    tooltip
      .style("opacity", 0.8)//
      .style("top", y(data[d].year)-y.bandwidth()+"px")
      .style("left", x(data[d].value)+"px")
      .html("Year: " + data[d].year+ "<br>Value: "+data[d].value);//
  }
  const mouseleave = function(event,d) {
    tooltip
      .style('opacity', 0)
  }
  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
```

And this to your css:

```
#tooltip{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 90%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

It will give you something like this:
[image: Output of the tooltip]

I know its not so minimalistic but i think you can edit this and make it something you like.

```js
  const data = [
            { year: "2019", value: 11 },
            { year: "2020", value: 10 },
            { year: "2021", value: 23 },
            { year: "2022", value: 37.4 },
        ];

        const svg = d3.select(".bar-chart");
        const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 60 };
        const width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".bar-chart-container")).width) - margin.left - margin.right;
        const height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".bar-chart-container")).height) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        // Add the gradient definition
        const gradient = svg.append("defs")
            .append("linearGradient")
            .attr("id", "bar-gradient")
            .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("x2", width)
            .attr("y2", 0);

        gradient.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "0%")
            .attr("stop-color", "#80bede");

        gradient.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "100%")
            .attr("stop-color", "#acd6d9");

        const x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
            .range([0, width]);

        const y = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map(d => d.year))
            .range([0, height])
            .padding(0.3);

        const g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

        // Create and append the bars
        g.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("y", d => y(d.year))
            .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
            .attr("fill", "url(#bar-gradient)")
            .attr("width", 0)
            .transition()
            .duration((d, i) => 500 + i * 200)
            .attr("width", d => x(d.value))

        g.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
            .call(g => g.selectAll("line").remove()) // Remove y-axis lines
            .call(g => g.selectAll("path").remove()) // Remove y-axis lines
            .call(g => g.selectAll("text") // Change font color of y-axis labels
                .style("fill", "#bbbbbb") // Change the fill color here
            );
  const tooltip = d3.select(".bar-chart-container")
    .append("div")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("id", "tooltip");
  const mouseover = function(event, d) {
    tooltip
      .style("opacity", 0.8)//
      .style("top", y(data[d].year)-y.bandwidth()+"px")
      .style("left", x(data[d].value)+"px")
      .html("Year: " + data[d].year+ "<br>Value: "+data[d].value);//
  }
  const mouseleave = function(event,d) {
    tooltip
      .style('opacity', 0)
  }
  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
```

```css
#tooltip{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 90%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar-chart-container">
  <svg class="bar-chart"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: it does not appear to work, can you tell me why?

Comment: I can't tell why is it not working whitout looking at your code, i added a snippet code to my answer for you to see how it works

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to open  toltip on hover of bar  just append your rect with title element and add your data into *text***

```js
 const data = [
            { year: "2019", value: 11 },
            { year: "2020", value: 10 },
            { year: "2021", value: 23 },
            { year: "2022", value: 37.4 },
        ];

        const svg = d3.select(".bar-chart");
        const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 60 };
        const width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".bar-chart-container")).width) - margin.left - margin.right;
        const height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".bar-chart-container")).height) - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        // Add the gradient definition
        const gradient = svg.append("defs")
            .append("linearGradient")
            .attr("id", "bar-gradient")
            .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
            .attr("x1", 0)
            .attr("y1", 0)
            .attr("x2", width)
            .attr("y2", 0);

        gradient.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "0%")
            .attr("stop-color", "#80bede");

        gradient.append("stop")
            .attr("offset", "100%")
            .attr("stop-color", "#acd6d9");

        const x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)])
            .range([0, width]);

        const y = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map(d => d.year))
            .range([0, height])
            .padding(0.3);

        const g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

        // Create and append the bars
     let bar=   g.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("y", d => y(d.year))
            .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
            .attr("fill", "url(#bar-gradient)")
            .attr("width", 0)
            
            bar.transition()
            .duration((d, i) => 500 + i * 200)
            .attr("width", d => x(d.value))
             bar.append("title").text((d,i) =>"Year: " + d.year+ "\n Value: "+d.value)
             
        g.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
            .call(g => g.selectAll("line").remove()) // Remove y-axis lines
            .call(g => g.selectAll("path").remove()) // Remove y-axis lines
            .call(g => g.selectAll("text") // Change font color of y-axis labels
                .style("fill", "#bbbbbb") // Change the fill color here
            );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar-chart-container">
  <svg class="bar-chart"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Shanu but if you run your code, the tooltip does not appear. I'm not using react.

Comment: it's not related to react it's rect  and if you run my code you will get tooltip on hover